# QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context

Tags: qt5, yocto

I've been trying to add Qt5 support to a `core-image-sato` image using Yocto's Poky Pyro on Raspberry Pi 3.

In my bblayer.conf I added these lines:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
        /poky-pyro/meta \
        /poky-pyro/meta-poky \
        /poky-pyro/meta-yocto-bsp \
        /poky-pyro/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
        /poky-pyro/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
        /poky-pyro/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
        /poky-pyro/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
        /poky-pyro/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
        /poky-pyro/meta-raspberrypi \
        /poky-pyro/meta-qt5 \
  "
```

In my local.conf I added these lines:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " opengl "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " qtbase qtdeclarative qtquickcontrols2 qtmultimedia qttools cinematicexperience "
```

Bitbake finished building the image successfully, but when I run Qt5_cenimaticExperience on the target I get this error message:

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled.
```

Comment: You can check which features are enabled in the log.do_configure (at its very end) of your qtbase build. Most likely you will find that egl is not enabled. In your qtbase recipe you can find the different features that you can activate via the packageconfig variable. The easiest (quick and dirty) way is probably to just make a qtbase.bbappend recipe where you add the features you want by appending to the packageconfig variable. Should look somewhat like: `PACKAGECONFIG += " eglfs"` (mind the space at the beginning of the string)

Comment: Are you sure it's the right thing to use `eglfs` with X11 window system?

Comment: I am not entirely sure that it is "right", as I mentioned this is a quick and dirty way you could try. If it works, you have narrowed your problem down and you may take a more sophisticated approach if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default configuration of Qtbase and based on what you have:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_GL ?= "${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'opengl', 'gl', '', d)}"
PACKAGECONFIG_DEFAULT ?= "dbus udev evdev widgets tools libs freetype tests"
PACKAGECONFIG_SYSTEM ?= "jpeg libpng zlib"
```

As you can see, we only enabled `-opengl desktop`;  What we need is `opengl es2` for embedded system.

To correct this, add this line to your `local.conf`:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase = " gles2 "
```

By the way, this is my qtbase configuration:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase = " gles2 fontconfig \
                gstreamer \
                accessibility \
                tslib examples \
                "
```

Comment: Thank you @Charles for your answer. I tried your solution but it didn't work, Do you have any idea why ?